# capitalizing initial character in game maker studio

Tags: game-maker

The value "V_Output" is the string of letters that I wish to capitalize the initial of. The following code is run in the step event.

```
V_InitL=string_char_at(V_Output,1)
V_InitL_Cap=string_upper(V_InitL)

string_delete(V_Output,0,1)
string_insert(V_InitL_Cap,V_Output,1)
```

The resultant output as is produced in the draw event shows the original, un-capitalized version.

The following debug changes produce no detectable effect:

```
V_InitL=string_char_at(V_Output,1)
V_InitL_Cap=string_upper(V_InitL)

string_delete(V_Output,0,1)
string_insert("DEBUG",V_Output,1)
```

Why is this happening? What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code fixed the problem:

```
V_InitL=string_char_at(V_Output,1)
V_InitL_Cap=string_upper(V_InitL)

V_Output=string_delete(V_Output,1,1)
V_Output=string_insert(V_InitL_Cap,V_Output,1)
```

As it turns out the effect of the last two functions can only be acquired if the variable has its value reassigned to the output of the functions (by adding "V_Output=" in front)

Also, to delete single character, the index must be that of the target character.